# Django query spanning multiple relationships with indirection

Tags: python, django

My question is about querying objects spanning across multiple relationships, with a twist. I don't know how to translate what seems like a simple SQL query into its equivalent in Django.

Here's a cut down version of my models (I removed the noise) :

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
    assigned_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="ProjectAssignment")

class CostProfile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    default_daily_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

class CostRate(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(CostProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    daily_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

class ProjectAssignment(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cost_profile = models.ForeignKey(CostProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Users can be assigned to multiple `Project`s, with a given `CostProfile` as extra field of the many-to-many relationship. A `Project` also has multiple `CostRate`s, that can override the default daily rate on a `ProjectAssignment`'s `CostProfile`.

I want to list all `ProjectAssignment`s, with the referenced user, the cost profile, its default daily rate and finally the related cost rate if there is one for this project and cost profile. The difficulty is on the last bit : matching the related `CostRate` if there is one. The SQL query would be like this (sticking to IDs for project and user to keep it readable):

```sql
SELECT gp.project_id, gp.user_id , cp.title, cp.default_daily_rate, gc.daily_rate
FROM projectassignment gp
LEFT OUTER JOIN costprofile cp ON cp.id = gp.cost_profile_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN costrate cr ON cr.cost_profile_id  = cp.profile_id AND cr.project_id=gp.project_id
```

I know how to get the first 4 fields with a Django query, but not the last one :

```py
ProjectAssignment.objects.values("project__title", "user__username", "cost_profile__title", "cost_profile__default_daily_rate")
```

The trick seems to be on the last LEFT OUTER JOIN, which uses fields from not only projectassignment but also costrate.

How would I translate this into a Django query ? My gut feeling is that I have to use a Subquery, but I'm not sure how.